# How to fix jslint error 'Don't make functions within a loop.' while using find function inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, eslint

I am working to resolve all JSLint errors in my JS files.

Currently it shows 'Don't make functions within a loop.'on below sample code.

```
While(condition)
{
const userObj = find(users, user => user.id === currUserid);
}
```

currUserid is user id.
users is array of user.

I have tried to create separate function and pass it like below.

```
userChk = (user, id) => {
    if (user.id === id) {
      return user;
    }
} 
While(condition)
{
   const userObj = find(users, userChk(currUserid));
}
```

But error shows like 'currUserid is not a function'. It will work fine if i do not pass currUserid value. But i can not check for different user ids. Please help me to find a better solution for this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function findUser(users, currUserid) {
  return find(users, user => user.id === currUserid)
}


while(condition) {
  const userObj = findUser(users, currUserid);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Thanks for your help. @Ritesh Bansal